# One-to-One relationship using Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to populate a DataGrid using WebAPI 2 **Get** method. I have a **User** class and a **UserAddress** calss having **one-to-one** relationship between them and their code goes as follows:

```
public partial class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserType { get; set; }

    public virtual UserAddress UserAddress { get; set; }
}

public partial class UserAddress
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserAddress1 { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

The code at my client side goes as follows:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            //HTTP Get
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/Users");
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var users = response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<User>>().Result;
                grdList.ItemsSource = users;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show(response.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
```

The code of the Controller class is as follows:

```
// GET: api/Users
    public IQueryable<User> GetUsers()
    {
        return db.Users;
    }
```

I am able to retrieve data without any relationship but with one-to-one relationship I am unable to do so and I can't understand where the problem is.

Comment: Do you mean that in your client code your User.UserAddress is null ?

Comment: No there is value in it .I had entered the value using post method

Comment: Personally i don't understand your issue.

Comment: I want to retrieve data using get method but I am getting error.

Comment: Don't even try to point me the error or exception message ! I know everything without your hints !

Comment: what do u mean by that I can't understand.

Comment: I am able to retrieve data without any relationship but with one-to-one relationship I am unable to do so and I can't understand where the problem is.

Comment: What does `I am unable` mean ??????????? Do you have some exception in client side ? If yes than what exception ? Or maybe you have server side exception ? Or maybe your server response is empty ? Or maybe it is not empty but some properties are empty ? HOW can i know it ?!

Comment: The response I am getting is "server error".

Comment: I'd keep data normalized and merge the classes

Answer (score -1):

It may be the circular reference issue if you are returning Json see the section in the following link
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization

Specifically the part related to Handling Circular Object References and configuring the JsonMediaTypeFormatter

var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
   json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =       Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All;

One other part that I was wondering about is if you needed to perform eager loading with linq to return addresses?

return db.users.Include(p=>p.address)